# Not matching a character at the beginning of line

Tags: regular-expressions

I would like to match lines that have the phrase `a test` but not start with `>`. So I want to match

```
This is a test
a test this is
```

but not

```
> This is a test
```

I am not sure how to do this without lookahead in emacs.

As a first try I tried`^[^>].*a test`. However, for some reason, this matches `> This is a test` when there's a newline before it which I don't understand since the first character in a line should not be `>`.

What is the correct regular expression for this case? And why is my regular expression matching lines starting with `>`.

[image: emacs screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the construct `[^>]` matches even a newline as stated in https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression. Indeed such regex matches even the line above. So replacing it with `[^>\n]` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must be something else; that regex looks fine to me. In fact, I used `M-x regexp-builder` to verify that it does work as expected.

Comment: I just tried it with `regexp-builder` with `emacs -Q` and I am still getting `> This is a test` matched (I am adding an image to show this in my post). However, I now understand that the problem seems to be that if there is an empty line before `> This is a test` then I get the incorrect match (I edited my post to reflect this). Any idea why this is and how to fix it?